# I stuck with some code when i read Collective Intelligence

Tags: python

Recently i read *Collective Intelligence* wrote by Toby Segaran. But i was stuck in understanding some code in the book.

Here's some the code in the recommendations.py

The code below is to returns the best matches for person from the preference dictionary and get recommendations for a person by using a weighted average
 of every other user's rankings

```
# Return the Pearson correlation coefficient for p1 and p2
def sim_person(prefs, p1, p2):
    # Get the list of shared_items
    si={}
    for item in prefs[p1]:
        if item in prefs[p2]:si[item]=1

    # Find the number of elements 
    n=len(si)

    # if they have no ratings in common, return 0
    if n==0: return 0

    # Add up all the preferences
    sum1 = sum([prefs[p1][it] for it in si])
    sum2 = sum([prefs[p2][it] for it in si])

    # Sum up the squares
    sum1Sq = sum([pow(prefs[p1][it],2) for it in si])
    sum2Sq = sum([pow(prefs[p2][it],2) for it in si])

    # Sum up the products
    pSum = sum([prefs[p1][it]*prefs[p2][it] for it in si])

    # Calculate Person score
    num = pSum - (sum1*sum2/n)
    den = sqrt((sum1Sq - pow(sum1,2)/n)*(sum2Sq - pow(sum2,2)/n))
    if den == 0: return 0

    r = num/den
    return r

# Returns the best matches for person from the prefs dictionary.
# Number of results and similarity function are optional params.
def topMatch(prefs, person, n=5, similarity=sim_person):
    scores = [(similarity(prefs, person, other), other) 
                        for other in prefs if other!=person]

    # Sort the list so the highest scores appear at the top
    scores.sort()
    scores.reverse()
    return scores[0:n]

# Gets recommendations for a person by using a weighted average
# of every other user's rankings 
def getRecommendations(prefs, person, similarity=sim_person):
    totals = {}
    simSums = {}
    for other in prefs:
        # don't compare me to myself
        if other == person: continue
        sim = similarity(prefs, person, other)

        # ignore scores of zero of lower
        if sim<=0: continue
        for item in prefs[other]:

            # only score movies I haven't seen yet
            if item not in prefs[person] or prefs[person][item]==0:
                # Similarity * Score
                totals.setdefault(item, 0)
                totals[item]+=prefs[other][item]*sim
                # Sum of similarities
                simSums.setdefault(item, 0)
                simSums[item]+=sim

        # Create the normalized list 
        rankings = [(total/simSums[item], item) for item, total in totals.items()]

        # Return the sorted list 
        rankings.sort()
        rankings.reverse()
        return rankings
```

The first code i could not understand is:

```
scores = [(similarity(prefs, person, other), other) for other in prefs if other!=person]
```

Does the second other in this sentence mean a parameter? Can i change this code into:

```
scores = [(similarity(prefs, person, other) for other in prefs if other!=person]
```

The second code I could not understand is:

```
rankings = [(total/simSums[item], item) for item, total in totals.items()]
```

Comment: what is `similarity`?

Comment: @AdamSmith i added the code again :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're constructing tuples. Compare:

```
coordinates = (10, 2)
```

with

```
some_score = (similarity(prefs, person, other), other)
```

You're creating a 2-element tuple. The first element is `similarity(prefs, person, other)` and the second element is `other`.

Comment: I didn't realise that is a tuple before. Thank you Adam. It's really a great help.  :-)